# How to post detailed test results to slack with fastlane?

Tags: ios, xcode, automated-tests, slack, fastlane

I want to post detailed results of my tests to slack using fastlane. When glancing at the tests running from fastlane in my terminal, I notice I have reports such as name of each test, time spent on each test, which ones failed, and with what error. Currently, I have my fastfile set up as described in this doc (at the bottom where it says "Posting Build Results".
https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/running-tests/
However, this only sends number of tests run and number of failures to my slack channel. Is there a way to get a more detailed "report card" of all the tests that ran?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the Fastlane tool "scan" to get a generalized report of your test cases, it comes up with a HTML page of the test statistics.

https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/run_tests/

If you want a test coverage report then you should use the other tool "xcov" which will give you coverage report of each file which is included in the test case.

https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/xcov/

Comment: is there a way to post that html page/the information it contains to slack?